# one dedicated directory for node_modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am quite new to npm but I have a question about npm node modules. I have the node modules now installed in several directories. One for Gulp, one for nodeJS etc. I was wondering how I could have one dedicated node modules directory and let the other packages point to that directory, instead of having node modules all over the place.

What is best practise?

Cheers,
Lino

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question - are you asking if you can have a single node_modules for your whole machine? If so, no, not really - and you wouldn't want to, as it would take away one of the key benefits of having a package manager (isolated dependencies, independent projects, builds that act predictably on multiple machines).

Comment: You can install packages globally using `npm install -g packagename`, but this is more intended to be used for installing stuff like command line tools, not things that your project will depend on. I'm not 100% sure whether you can even import global packages into a Node program, but either way - it's usually a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have global node_modules directory accessible to multiple application. 
A package is available globally if it is installed with -g option. For instance if body-parser is required globally it should be installed with the following npm command:

npm install body-parser -g

Following are the paths are usage of modules:

- Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current
  package root.
- Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever
  node is installed.
- Install it locally if you're going to       require() it.
- Install it    globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
- If you    need both, then install it in both places, or use
  npm link.